# Active Directory: Query if user is logged

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to query a LDAP server to get information if an user is logged in or not.

In a collection of properties (from return) none tell me specifically the information, but there are two in particullar that can do this: lastlogon and lastlogoff.
But lastlogoff it is always 0.
: /

How I can get the real value of lastlogoff?

Answer (score 0):

May I refer you to this article on SO? I used this solution before, because as noted, there was no method of finding this information within AD. One could seek out the computer names on the network, but this does not indicate the actual user.

[Active Directory check if user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327063/active-directory-check-if-user-is-logged-in)

I hope this is helpful to you, i used this from the linked article....

> "...Another alternative could be to craft a logon/logoff script that
>   writes to a particular file/database and you could monitor that file
>   to see who is logged in...."

Then, this exmaple is for vbscript and WMI. As stated, a third party tool available through sysinternals exists.
You said you have no access to change LDAP server. Does this include logon/logoff scripts?

Here is the link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/03/04/how-to-get-the-logged-on-user-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx

Comment: tks Levi. Another alternative is good, however I can't change anything on the LDAP server.